# Copy Elastic Beanstalk Configuration across accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

If i use the [eb-cli](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-cmd-commands.html) `eb config save` to save the configuration of my current environment it works to start a new one using `eb create`.

But if i want to create the same environment with a different AWS account obviously lines like the following make no sence:

```
aws:ec2:vpc:
    Subnets: subnet-2d9a3c56
    VPCId: vpc-1dff4c74
```

So how can i build the same elastic beanstalk environment within multiple accounts? Is there any way to tell AWS? Maybe an "Account Agnostic" config-save?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would not be possible to build the **exact** same ElasticBeanstalk environment across accounts.  The environment is going to have resource IDs such as VPCs and Subnets that will be different.

A good way to build *effectively* the same ElasticBeanstalk application across multiple accounts would be to use CloudFormation to configure the environments.  This requires a different approach to creating environments, but also means that the configuration can be more easily version controlled.

Comment: JaredHatfield thanks for your comment. I thought about this as well. But so far i do not see the difference between manually modifying the configuration (e.g. removing ID's of Subnets etc) and using a "AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ConfigurationTemplate". Maybe i am wrong, but the Template uses "OptionSettings" which are the same as produced by the config-Tool. Just in another format.

See: 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-elasticbeanstalk.html

Answer (score 1):

With cloudformation you can specify the parameters to be selected to feed into the template when the stack is being created.

You can use the {"Ref" : ""} method to create drop down lists of Subnets in the VPC etc

This would be the way I would do it.