# How to move/clone an Elastic Beanstalk Environment between (Elastic Beanstalk) Applications

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm new to AWS. For simplicity I have been working with a number of separate **Elastic Beanstalk Environments**, within the same **Elastic Beanstalk Application**

I have come to understand that **Applications** are *just* folders for **Environments**.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts.html

I'm just trying to get more organized. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, applications are not *literally* folders for environments, according to the documentation an application is "a logical collection of Elastic Beanstalk components".

The idea behind it is to have a single codebase that get deployed to several environments with different configuration depending on your needs. You can have several **application versions** (or the same version if you want it that way) deployed in several scenarios (**environments**) with varying configurations, let's say different environment variables, or different values for them, different infrastructure, etc. So, from my point of view there's not much logic in cloning an environment to a different application, since usually different applications would require different configurations.

But, if for your particular needs, you have very similar applications (they use the same platform, consume some of the same resources and basically you wanna deploy them in a very similar way infrastructure-wise) I think a good idea could be writing configuration files for your desired environment and just add those to your different application's code (you can find the official documentation on .ebextensions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html), they even give you [this link](https://github.com/awsdocs/elastic-beanstalk-samples/tree/master/configuration-files) with several common configuration files). Another approach could be directly using CloudFormation templates as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34774380/copy-elastic-beanstalk-configuration-across-accounts) and just recreate the entire application from a CF template.

I hope this helped

Comment: Thanks @Lawrence. Completely agree now. The AWS UX for ElasticBeanstalk was an afterthought.  These "folders" are meaningless, besides as a logical grouping.

I ended-up teaching my CloudFormation templates, and now avoid the web interface at all cost :/

Answer (score 2):

Just for someone like me who came here for solutions...

Actually you can clone a environment from one Application to another Application with some steps.

Just follow this [AWS - How do I migrate my Elastic Beanstalk environment from one AWS account to another AWS account?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-migration-accounts/)

This doc tells you how to do it between 2 AWS accounts but you can do it in just one account. The idea is just:

- Save Config in one Application
- Load Config in another Application